# When adding Runat="Server" tag to HTML table, the sharepoint not displaying the usercontrol

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have an .ascx control. That is having few Html table and Div section Runat = "Server"

The Code looks like following,

```
<div id = "divpayinfo" runat = "server">

<%!-- Some Code Here --%>

 <table style="width: 403px" runat = "server">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 63px; height: 22px;">
                    test</td>
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 22px">
                    <strong><span style="color: #ffffff">ผู้ขอกู้หลัก</span></strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 63px; height: 21px">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 180px; height: 21px">
                    <strong>วงเงิน</strong></td>
                <td style="height: 21px">
                    <strong>ยอดคงค้าง</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 63px">
                    1. เงินกู้เพื่อที่อยู่อาศัย</td>
                <td style="width: 180px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_lh_loan_h_all" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right"
                        MaxLength="8" onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_all'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_all'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_all'))"
                        Text="0" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_lh_loan_h_all" runat="server"
                            Text="0"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_lh_loan_h_remain" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right"
                        MaxLength="8" onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_h_remain'))"
                        Text="0" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_lh_loan_h_remain" runat="server"
                            Text="0"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 63px; height: 102px;">
                    2. เงินกู้เบิกเกินบัญชี</td>
                <td style="width: 180px; height: 102px;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_lh_loan_a_all" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right"
                        MaxLength="8" onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_all'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_all'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_all'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_all'))"
                        Text="0" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_lh_loan_a_all" runat="server"
                            Text="0"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td style="height: 102px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_lh_loan_a_remain" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right"
                        MaxLength="8" onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'),document.getElementById('b_txt_lh_loan_a_remain'))"
                        Text="0" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_lh_loan_a_remain" runat="server"
                            Text="0"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I am doing some manupulation with DIV and HTML table at server side. so that i have mentioned as Server Side. I upload this control to Sharepoint as formusercontrolwebpart.

The Problem is when i upload the table with runat="Server" tag, the usercontrol is not displaying at sharepoint page... So that I copy this table and create another ascx only with this table and upload it to sharepoint but this is working fine.

I have checked all my user control code and adding with ASP.NET application. The usercontrol is working as expectedly there is no problem. But only when i adding with Sharepoint page it is giving problem..

I have found the following solution,

Remove all the runat = "server" tag from every Div section and add runat ="server" to table then the sharepoint page is working. But my problem is i have lot of manupulation with Div tag at server side.So that I cannot use this solution..

Please advise me experts.. is there anyway sharepoint protecting runat = "server" tag from usercontrol or anything related to that... Thank you in advance..

If I add follwing lines of code then my user control display not rendering,

```
<asp:TableCell id="d_div_l2_row9" runat="server" style="display: none; vertical-align: middle;
                    text-align: center">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_l2_comission" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right" MaxLength="8"
                        onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        Text="0" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox><span style="display: none"><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_l2_comission"
                            runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox></span></asp:TableCell>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, Any tag with `runat="server"` cause the user control to disappear?

Comment: Dear Banana, runat = "server" tag working fine until some line. But when i insert runat sever after specific line then the usercontrol not displaying.. i have checked the code throughly my usercontrol is working fine with my asp.net webapplication.. but it is not working in sharepoint page

Comment: Did you try to debug and see if there is an exception?

Comment: I already found some workaround for this problem.. still cant able to found the exact problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moose,Andrew and Banana,

Thank you so much for your efforts to help me out.

I found another way to acheive the solution but still it is headache for me to find out the cause.

I uploaded the same usercontrol in sharepoint server "control template" folder and I have created an .aspx page for that user control and upload the aspx in sharepoint. now it is working fine the way it was working with asp.net application.

Comment: Please mark this as accepted so this question is marked as resolved and won't appear as open in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think asp:panel gets converted to a div in the underlying HTML. You could try that;

```
<asp:panel id="divpayinfo" runat="server">

  <!-- Your code here -->

</asp:panel>
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Moose, Right now i am converting all the Div Section to Panel and All the HTML table to be ASP:Table.. But my problem is there are lot of Div and Table :) probably around 8 tables and 25 Div section.. Thats why i am trying to find out the core problem.. If you have any suggestion please share whether any security related in sharepoint that prevent my Div and Table not working together :(

Comment: I have converted all my DIV and Table to be ASP.NET Panel and asp:Table but still same problem i am facing.. i Found at some point from oneline if i remove runat = "server" tag then i could be able to view the user control... I am not sure what is the cause for this error :(

Comment: Sorry. I don't have many other ideas. Can you view the source and then see if the divs and tables are present? Maybe there is some Javascript that is adjusting the visible property or something similar?

Comment: Mr Moose I comment out all the js.. even though still same problem.. Thank you so much for ur comments

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TableCell id="d_div_l2_row9" runat="server" style="**display: none;** vertical-align: middle;
                    text-align: center">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="b_txt_l2_comission" runat="server" CssClass="box_nosize_right" MaxLength="8"
                        onchange="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        onfocus="To_Get_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        onmouseout="To_Set_Value(document.getElementById('d_txt_l2_comission'),document.getElementById('b_txt_l2_comission'))"
                        Text="0" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox><span style="display: none"><asp:TextBox ID="d_txt_l2_comission"
                            runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox></span></asp:TableCell>
```

Text display:none in the style is this generated or added by you. Cause this means that control should not be displayed.

Comment: Dear Andrew, Yes this will not be visible to UI and I dont do any manupulation with this textbox....Even Instead of this textbox if i add one another control with runat = server tag like <div id="testctl" runat="server">Testcall</div>.. then also not displaying.. i comment javascript and my Business & DB layer too.. no luck.. still get confuse about sharepoint.. i add the usercontrol in my asp.net application it is working fine but sharepoint page only giving me problem